# Customer output through terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, terraform

As we are able to display predefined variables `aws_instance.my-instance.public_ip` values through `output variables` at the end of the execution of terraform apply.

Similar way, is there a way to output custom information from the new instance at the end such as output a system file any command output such `echo hello!` or `cat /var/log/hello.log`?

Comment: It's not supported by default, but you could use something like https://github.com/matti/terraform-shell-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Terraform Provisioners. They are basically interface to run commands and script to remote machine (or local depending over the provisioner) to achieve some tasks, which in most cases will be bootstrapping matters.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-b374d5a5"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${aws_instance.example.public_ip} > ip_address.txt"
  }
}
```

You can read more about them here: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/provision

**However**, keep in mind that provisioners are terraform objects and not bound to instances, so they only execute when you use Terraform to spin up or edit instances. These bootstrapping scripts wont come into effect if your instance is created by an ASG during an scale-out operation or by an orchestration tool. For that purpose, using instance's `user_data` is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

As @SajjadHashmi, you can use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run commands on your local host with some limitations.

Thus in desperation you can use `ssh` and `scp` commands on your local host to get the files from from the instance and execute commands there. This is **not a very nice way**, but as a measure of the last resort could be considered in some scenarios.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {

  # other attributes
    
  provisioner "local-exec" {
  
    command = <<-EOL
    
      # give time to instance to properly boot
      sleep 30
      
      # download a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log 
      # file from the instance to the host's /tmp folder
      scp -i private_ssh_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${self.public_ip}:/var/log/cloud-init-output.log /tmp
      
      # execute command ls -a on the instance and save output to 
      # local file /tmp/output.txt
      ssh -i private_ssh_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${self.public_ip} ls -a >> /tmp/output.txt
    EOL
  }   

}
```